# xCode 6 resize Input moves ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode

Not sure why it's doing this, but I can't figure how to get it to stop. The view controller moves left when you attempt to resize the input field. The example video is a new project after rebooting, and everything. Totally confused and driving me nuts. Any ideas?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dX-s-RvDCk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding down the command key as you resize to get the expected behavior.  Also, try dragging the right end of the input field to resize.  There seems to be a new "feature" where the left side resize moves the view controller as you resize by default.